# C++ Validation Message

Tags: c++

I gets multiple time of error message after input multiple characters. For example:"1300412". It seem like bring the input to loop, so it keep showing me "invalid input".
how to fix it to let it only show out "invalid input" for only once after a wrong input entered.

here is me code, please help me.

```
void main(){
char option;

do{

    system("cls");
    cout << " Select Function: " << endl;
    cout << "(a) Asset Depreciation." << endl;
    cout << "(b) Printing Charge." << endl;
    cout << "(c) Packaging Program." << endl;
    cout << "(q) Exit." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your option:";
    cin >> option;
    option = toupper(option);
    if (option == 'A'){
        Asset_Depreciation();
    }
    else if (option == 'B'){
        Printing_Charge();
    }
    else if (option == 'C'){
        Packaging_Program();
    }
    else if (option == 'Q'){
        cout << "Thanks For Using" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else{
        cout << "Invalid input!!! Please enter again." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        system("pause");
    }
} while (option!='Q');

}
```

Comment: Use `std::getline` and read the entire line as string. Then you can do `if (option == "A"){`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `option` is of type `char` it can not hold more than a character. This is why you get error message.

If you wish to input a `string` as input.

```
std::string var; // This will accept input this white space or \n occurred. 
std::cin >> var;
```

If you wish to to input a line of `string`

```
std::string var;
getline(std::cin,var); // This will accept input until \n has not entered.
```

After that all your comparison is going to be like this

```
if (option == "A"){
    Asset_Depreciation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore();
```

is simply useless. In accordance with the reference documentation:
[clear method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) and [ignore method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/).

The first method refers about the internal state of the stream.

The second method, used without parameters, simply ignores *just one character* from the input stream.

I suggest you to use it in this way:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());
```

Including at the begin the header for limit:

```
 #include <limits>
```

In that way you should be able to ignore and flush all the remaining characters in the stream which are no read yet.